# Advice on a database solution for a mobile app (Android/ iOS)

Tags: android, ios, database

I'd like to create a cross-platform mobile app.

The app would need to be connected to a database; my question is this: can anyone suggest a solution in which data can be manually entered into the database is a nice presentable human GUI that is shared with the mobile app?

I'd like a staff member to manually add data that our clients can then search for using our app.

I am sure that this is a very simple 'problem' that we are trying to solve - I guess I'm just looking for solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question is appropriate for stack overflow but the solution is to create a Web Admin panel using angular, react or laravel. In that admin panel you can have different form to enter the data and data tables to view and manage the data. The mobile apps should be connected to the same backend using RestAPIs that should be developed using any technology preferably node.js. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Realm` check the website [here](https://realm.io/). They have some concept of Realm cloud which is what you might be looking for whereas "Realm Studio" is a GUI app where an admin can add data from the server and will be reflected on the mobile side.

`Realm` works with both iOS and Android and can even export/ import data from JSON.

PS: Do check the pricing of it before you start using it in your project.